# How to create a web app with VueJS and NodeJS on AWS?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, vue.js

I've a web app executing locally but I want put it on AWS. The app consist on three  parts:

- VueJS app (frontend)
- NodeJS (backend/middleware)
- PostgreSQL

I never worked with AWS and the tutorials just work with a single NodeJS app. So, which services and how use that to make my whole application? Looking on the AWS's catalog I think that I can use the Beanstalk and AmazonRDS services, or AmazonS3 and AmazonRDS. Please anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is all the services you need for your app with Amazon :

- VueJS app => You can host it in a S3 bucket. **[Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/s3/index.html)** seems good for it.
- PostgresSQL => **[Amazon RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rds/index.html)** is the service you need.
- NodeJS => You will need **[Amazon EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/concepts.html)** to host your nodeJS app.

You can find a lot of tutorials into internet. There are so many... You can begin to [deploy your app into S3](https://itnext.io/deploy-vue-app-to-aws-s3-1256ce03a7a2). It is the easy part. Once you did that, you can look into [how to deploy nodeJS app into EC2](https://medium.com/@nishankjaintdk/setting-up-a-node-js-app-on-a-linux-ami-on-an-aws-ec2-instance-with-nginx-59cbc1bcc68c). And finally [connect your app to Amazon RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-nodejs.rds.html).

Comment: How I can find tutorials explaining how I connect the 3 services?

Comment: I put some links, but I just googled it. Your question is very large, you need to go step by step. First deploy your app into S3, then deploy your nodeJS app into EC2 and finally use RDS.

Comment: Thank for your help, I will try these solutions. I can deploy nodeJS on S3?

Comment: No you can't, the purpose of S3 is to host static content. Your nodeJS app need to work into a server, the results you can have from it are dynamic. In the other hand, your vue.js is delivred to a browser. It is a static resource that a browser downloads.